# Is concatenated string on where clause SARGable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have a nonclustered index on two nvarchar columns, A and B.

If my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT Columns FROM Table WHERE A + B = '1234'
```

Can the query effectively use the index?

Or should I separate the columns in where clause

```
SELECT Columns FROM Table WHERE A = '12' AND B = '34'
```

I've found pretty surprising results from my testings. Both produced an identical query plan, but the costs were different. Most of the time, the concatenated query would be faster but from time to time, the separated version would be faster.

Comment: I don't think such a query *can* be [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (meaning an index *can* be used); it seems like it would amount to `LIKE 'a%b'` .. but since you have the plans (and the specific schema/data/statistics), let's see them fighting numbers! Make sure to consider cost as the table size grows; even loop joins are fast (and sometimes faster) for small data sets. But alas, SQL Server surprises me quite often; usually pleasantly.

Comment: Hmm, my previous comment contradicts itself: `LIKE 'a%b'` can certainly use an index on the first part of the pattern. The correction would be "I don't think such a query can be can be SARGable *over both terms*.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any expression, function, calculation applied to column breaks `SARG`ability. The main formula looks like:

`column` `operator` `value` or

`value` `operator` `column`.

Column should be just column name. Operator can be `=, >, <=, >=, between, like`. Value can be constant or any expression.
`Like` should be like `like 'AAA%_`. If `Like` is `%AAA` or `_AAA` it is not `SARG`able.

So the answer is: if you can split your predicate to `WHERE A = '12' AND B = '34'`, this will use index if any appropriate exists. This `WHERE A + B = '1234'` won't use index.