# C# Lambda - EF Core, Col A+ Col B

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm looking for a way to select using lambda.. something similar to this TSQL

```
SELECT Id FROM TableA 
    WHERE TableA.col1 +' '+ TableA.col2 IN 
        (
            SELECT TableB.col1 +' '+ TableB.col2 FROM TableB
        )
```

so far I have this lambda expression:

```
public async Task<int[]> GetFavouritesIdsAsync()
{
    String[] mergedTableB = await _basicContext.TableB.Select(x => $"{x.col1}_{x.col2}").ToArrayAsync(); // this works!
    return await _basicContext.TableA.Where(x => mergedTableB.Contains($"{x.col1}_{x.col2}")).Select(x => x.Id).ToArrayAsync(); 
}
```

but it doesn't work - EF couldn't translate string.format bla bla....

any workaround?

Comment: Why? you may use inner join on A.1 = B.1 and A.2 = B.2 and get the same results

Comment: String concatenation is [not sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29406797/87698). I'm not terribly familiar with Entity Framework, but according to [this question, using `Any` should work to compare multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6912733/87698).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ, using simple join operation:

```
_basicContext.TableA.Join(
    _basicContext.TableB,
    a => new {a.col1, a.col2},
    b => new {b.col1, b.col2},
    (a, b) => a );
```

Workaround to existing attempt:

```
mergedTableB.Contains(x.col1 + "_" + x.col2)
```